# how to pass path and value of inner html input type to path of main input type in <form>?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a drop down menu in my form. When I select 'other'option in it an inner text box appears. Instead of selecting the option from the dropdown user prefers to enter the text. **How can i pass inner html path value(input type=text) entered by the user through path of dropdown menu(input type=select).** And i also want that when inner html is invoked the select input should be disabled.

here is my dropdown code

```
<form:select path="competitorName" name="competitorName" title="Choose a competitor"
                                        onchange="$('#competitor_name').val($.trim($('#myCompetitorId option:selected' ).text()));showfield(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)"
                                        id="myCompetitorId">
                                        <option value=" ">Please select an competitor</option>
                                        <c:forEach var="competitor" items="${competitors}">
                                            <option
                                                value="<c:out value="${competitor.competitorName}"/>">
                                                <c:out value="${competitor.competitorName}" />
                                            </option>

                                        </c:forEach>
                                        <option value="Other">Other</option>
                                    </form:select>
```

My javascript code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function showfield(name){
  if(name=='Other')document.getElementById('div1').innerHTML='<font size="0">Name</font><input type="text" name="competitorName" path="competitorName"/>;
  else document.getElementById('div1').innerHTML='';
}
</script>
```

Comment: Use the `onchange` Event. By the way, the `<font>` tag is dead. Use CSS.

Comment: @PHPglue how can i use it ?

Comment: What's with the XML?

Comment: @PHPglue Which XML are you talking?

Comment: `<c:forEach` and `</form:select>` and the like. I recognize `</form>`. You should separate your JavaScript from your HTML as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know about your XML, or whatever that is, but here's a function that might help.

```
//<![CDATA[
function selectToText(selectElement, textElement){
  selectElement.onchange = function(){
    if(textElement.value){
      textElement.value = this.value;
    }
    else{
      textElement.innerHTML = this.value;
    }
  }
}

var pre = onload, doc, bod, htm, E;
onload = function(){
if(pre)pre();

doc = document, bod = doc.body, htm = doc.documentElement;
E = function(id){
  return doc.getElementById(id);
}
selectToText(E('yourSelectId'), E('yourTextElementId'));

}
//]]>
```

Use external JavaScript, putting the `<script>` tag with a `src` attribute in your `<head>`. Of course, you have to change `'yourSelectId'` and `'yourTextElementId'` to the proper id's if you want to use my `E` function.

Comment: how should i call this function in my html?

Comment: Did you read the bottom of my post? You should have a basic understanding of HTML, at the bare minimum, to perform Client Side functionality. You can look up HTML tags and structures very easily online.